# include files on remote machine in a launch file (groovy)

Tags: roslaunch, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Say we have use this to introduce our machine in our launch file

How can I include a launch file which is on this remote machine (Robot) in my launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81296/include-files-on-remote-machine-in-a-launch-file-(groovy)/) by [Solmaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2778/solmaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's not possible as roslaunch files are fully evaluated on the launching machine before executing.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0